# how to uninstall 7z2201-linux-x64.tar.xz applications in ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall, tar, 7zip

`sudo apt-get purge 7z2201-linux-x64.tar.xz 7z2301-linux-x64.tar.xz`

Error like

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package 7z2201-linux-x64.tar.xz
E: Couldn't find any package by glob '7z2201-linux-x64.tar.xz'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex '7z2201-linux-x64.tar.xz'
E: Unable to locate package 7z2301-linux-x64.tar.xz
E: Couldn't find any package by glob '7z2301-linux-x64.tar.xz'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex '7z2301-linux-x64.tar.xz'

why??

Comment: `7z2201-linux-x64.tar.xz` is not an Ubuntu package - it's just an archive containing pre-built `7zz` and `7zzs` programs plus a user manual. If you copied the files somewhere manually then you will need to find and delete them.

Comment: Follow the instructions provided by the creator of the *tarball* (tar.xz; where xz is the compression used). The creator of the *archive* or *tarball* can follow whichever standards they wish to.  *If the installer didn't follow those instructions; reverse whatever they did*